# Displaying Nagios on a 52" 1080p screen

Tags: nagios

I'm using a 52" 1080p LCD screen to monitor Nagios, positioned where most of the users can see it.

Using the default Nagios web view sort of sucks, since you need to increase the text size a decent amount so it's legible from a distance, and then the "Current Network Status", "Host Status Totals", and other boxes along the top take up the majority of the screen realestate; you can't really see the list of host details.

Is there a custom view for Nagios, or a plugin, or something available which is meant to display Nagios details on a large screen with large text?

Comment: +1 for making your system sttus highly visible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would highly recommend nagvis from [here](http://www.nagvis.org/). This is a tremendous tool to display nagios data (from multiple nagios instances, if you want to) in a meaningful way. We also have such a TV on the wall, and we have around 10 different maps (that's like pages with diagrams and icons on it) rotating every 15 seconds. It's absolutely magic.

You will need some time to configure it, but the results are stunning. The screenshots on the site are only a small example of what can be done. If you have any questions about it, just fire away. We have about 200 hosts and 800 services in nagios across 3 sites, so there is very little I haven't done with nagios/nagvis.

Comment: Can you share screenshots for your Nagvis dashboards?

Answer (score 4):

You can use my open source project NagiosTV

https://github.com/chriscareycode/NagiosTV